# What are some other ways to say "more talk than walk"?

Tags: idioms

I know I've heard variations on this phrase before. Like "all talk and no action". I think there's another one about ranchers and hats...

Comment: "all bark, no bite"

Comment: See: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/all_hat_no_cattle/synonyms

Comment: All mouth and no trousers we say in England (or at least my mother did).

Comment: The original phrase is: to walk the walk, and to talk the talk. It's since been changed and shortened.

Comment: Demonstrating you have attempted to find the answer(s) to a question is always good, and required for some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase you are thinking of is "all hat and no cattle," which can be seen, for example, in the headline of [this](http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2010/05/05/bradley-blakeman-oil-spill-obama-day-hurricane-katrina-bush.html) 2010 article.

Comment: I thought Fox News was fake news...[caveat:  joke]

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard, supposedly of Native American origin, "Much thunder, no rain"

Comment: This one is cool